# Enable esm-apps on armhf

Tags: arm, esm

Since recently, it seems to be possible to get updates for software in `universe` by attaching it to a (free) Ubuntu Pro subscription.

This has worked on my desktop (amd64), so I also tried to do it on my NAS (armhf). Attaching the device has worked, but it didn't automatically enable the esm-apps repository. When trying it manually, it also didn't work:

```
> sudo pro enable esm-apps
One moment, checking your subscription first
Ubuntu Pro: ESM Apps is not available for platform armhf.
Supported platforms are: amd64, arm64, i386, ppc64el, s390x.
```

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: "Is there anything I can do?" Please do not ask questions that are answered with a yes or a no.  There is not much value in that. "Supported platforms are: amd64, arm64, i386, ppc64el, s390x." answers your question, The answer is no: no arm support.

Comment: Maybe remove the Pro subscription, re-install and use a *supported* architecture (ie. *arm64*) then re-attach the Pro subscription to your new-install.

Comment: I'm afraid that the CPU is ARMv7. I've looked at the repositories and there are some packages in there that are marked as `all` (some Python, Java and JavaScript packages) and it would be nice to get at least those updates.

Comment: It is not supported. So it doesn't make any sense to use it on this machine. You can get updates without it.

Comment: Ubuntu PRO allows you to get security *patches* (to 'universe' packages); not updates which are available with the PRO enabled.

Comment: "security patches" != "updates". LTS release generally don't update (that's their designed purpose!) Software updates are in the 6-month releases of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Pro subscription to get updates from `universe`.

ESM is an addition to `universe`.

ESM is not available for `armhf`. So you can remove the subscription from that machine.